# Python Control flow with line divisions

Tags: python

Currently maintaining a large application in Python and came across this:

```
if a \
    and b or c:
    d
elif a \
    and c:
    d
else:
    e
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` are boolean expressions, and `d` and `e` are statements to be executed. `d` is the same statement in each clause, so what the `if` and `elif` conditions really cause the same sequences to be executed (if my understanding is correct).

But say `d` was different for each block; then how would the logic be evaluated, particularly in the `if` block? Would it be like:

```
if a and (b or c)
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (a and e)
```

for `e` = `b or c`; or would it be more like

```
if (a and b) or c
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (e or c)
```

for `e` = `a and b` ?

My intuition is that it's the former, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Your title asks about the line divisions, but I don't see that that's relevant to your question.  Are you specifically asking about whether the line-continuation backslashes affect anything, or are you just asking about the relative precedence of `and` and `or`?

Comment: @BrenBarn, both are relevant to my question

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify the relevance of the line breaks.  Your question doesn't mention them at all, so it's not clear how they fit into what you're asking.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I imagine that the use of the line breaks in the code which I included and the subsequent question as to the equivalency of the other statements, which do NOT include line breaks, is enough to indicate quite clearly that the line breaks are relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the line with a `\` is just for code cleanliness, it does not affect the execution or evaluation order. Since `and` has higher precedence than `or`, the condition will be evaluated as `(a and b) or c`.